# MS Access Residual Query Parameters on Copied Report

Tags: ms-access

I've been working on an ms access database which was put together prior to my employment, I wanted to create a new report in order to display Quality Control information, in order to do this I copied the report which is used for producing quotes for customers (In order to retain the formatting).

I've almost completely redesigned the report and have just started writing some code to populate the report with data; I thought that I'd test the basics and added a SQL query as the report's record source.

Something like:

`SELECT [Quality Report].JobNo, [Quality Report].CaseNo FROM [Quality Report]`

At the moment there are no filters (WHERE clause) set.

For some reason, when loading the report outside of design view I'm receiving an InputBox() with the prompt "QuoteID", which indicates to me that there is some residual parameter from the report's previous usage; however I can't for the life of me figure out where it's coming from!

Any suggestions, ideas or answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check for VB code in the report?  The RecordSource may be set there.

Comment: Indeed I did and as expected it is blank; that was my first port of call.. I also thought that it was potentially still pointing at the report code for the original report but there is no code behind that one; it's very basic and all works off of record source and filters.

Comment: Through placing a redundant "0 As QuoteID" in my query I could workaround this but I'm intrigued/confused as to how this has happened!

Comment: Sounds like there may be a field, or a section, etc in the report with a control source of `QuoteID`.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the reply, apologies. It would certainly _seem_ so, but bugger knows where it is if that is the case, I clicked through the controls systematically trying to find it.